# Golang converting string to int64

Tags: string, go, int64

I want to convert a string to an int64. What I find from the `strconv` package is the `Atoi` function. It seems to cast a string to an int and return it:

```
// Atoi is shorthand for ParseInt(s, 10, 0).
func Atoi(s string) (i int, err error) {
        i64, err := ParseInt(s, 10, 0)
    return int(i64), err
}
```

The ParseInt actually returns an int64:

```
func ParseInt(s string, base int, bitSize int) (i int64, err error){
     //...
}
```

So if I want to get an int64 from a string, should I avoid using Atoi, instead use ParseInt? Or is there an Atio64 hidden somewhere?

Comment: `int` is a signed integer type that is *at least 32 bits* in size. It is a distinct type, however, and not an alias for `int32`. So you're good to use it and won't incur data loss in int64 range too

Answer (score 113, accepted):

No, there's no Atoi64. You should also pass in the 64 as the last parameter to ParseInt, or it might not produce the expected value on a 32-bit system.

```
var s string = "9223372036854775807"
i, _ := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
fmt.Printf("val: %v ; type: %[1]T\n", i)
```

https://play.golang.org/p/FUC8QO0-lYn

Comment: While your answer is correct, you could've added an example an make it SO-friendly

Answer (score 258):

Parsing string into int64 example:

```
// Use the max value for signed 64 integer. http://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#int64
var s string = "9223372036854775807"
i, err := strconv.ParseInt(s, 10, 64)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Printf("Hello, %v with type %s!\n", i, reflect.TypeOf(i))
```

output:

> Hello, 9223372036854775807 with type int64!

https://play.golang.org/p/XOKkE6WWer

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: One could also remove usage of reflect and use it just like; `fmt.Printf("Hello, %v with type %T!\n", i, i)` or even taking it another step further, one could use; `fmt.Printf("Hello, %v with type %[1]T!\n", i)`

Comment: I recommend strings.TrimSpace() because some unintended whitespace could change the numeric value by accident.

Comment: @PJBrunet Whitespace can give parsing errors, but how can it change the value?

Answer (score 5):

Another option:

```
package main
import "fmt"

func main() {
   var n int64
   fmt.Sscan("100", &n)
   fmt.Println(n == 100)
}
```

https://golang.org/pkg/fmt#Sscan